# NetSuite create one search for multiple record types

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have a field named company on NetSuite opportunity record, Which has list of both customers and prospects. I want to lookup that field and get location field from the record.

```
var company = currentRecord.getValue('entity');
var fieldLookUp = search.lookupFields({
type: search.Type.CUSTOMER, //I also want to add prospect here
id: company,
columns: ['location']});
```

I want to pass two record types : customer and prospect in lookup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use entity for the record type.  Entity is a valid type for searches.